# How to access the S3 folder using CloudFront signed cookie?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I want to build an HLS streaming server using Signed Cookie.

The video file is `video/test.m3u8` on the S3 bucket.

If `s3ObjectKey` is set to `vides/*` as in the picture, the file is not downloaded. `Access Denied` comes out.

If `s3ObjectKey` is set to `vidos/test.m3u8`, the file is downloaded.

[image]

I want to access all the files in the 'video' folder.

If it's not `vidoes/*`, I want to know how to set up to access all files.

There is no signed cookie example on ps. aws docunet.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're using `CookiesForCannedPolicy` in AWS SDK for Java. Since [canned policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html#private-content-choosing-canned-custom-cookies) doesn't support reusing the same policy statement for multiple files, I'll suggest that you can look into [CookiesForCustomPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudfront/CloudFrontCookieSigner.CookiesForCustomPolicy.html) which allows you to put `*` in the `resource` prop and give the permission to access all files in a directory.

For more details on custom policy, you can refer to this [developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-custom-policy.html)